# Uploading image functionality in table using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

hi am having a table which is acting like grid. Each row contains productID, followed by 4 columns with image 1,image 2,image 3,image 4. I was pretty happy with the data getting displayed but the requirement now to me is, On each image i have 2 links one is edit and other is delete. If image is already uploaded then edit the existing image else upload new image. 2nd option is to delete the image. Now how will I find which row and which column has the user clicked to upload or delete the image? Please help me to fix this I know this can be done using Jquery but I am not finding any help to get this things done

My View is here :

```
    <table id="listProduct">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.)*@
                Product ID
            </th>
            <th>Category / Sub Category 
            </th>
            <th>Image 1 
            </th>
            <th>Image 2 
            </th>
            <th>Image 3

            </th>
            <th>Image 4
            </th>
            <th>Product Status
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @*@Html.ActionLink(@item.ProductId, "FreezeProdView", "SellerLogin")*@
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductId)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category) / @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Subcategory)
                </td>
                <td width="20%" valign="top">
                    <img src ="@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ShoppingBag"].ToString()@item.Image1" id = "Img1_"@item.ProductId alt="" style="width:90px;height:115px;" />
                </td>
                <td width="20%" valign="top">
                    <img src ="@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ShoppingBag"].ToString()@item.Image2" id ="Img2_"@item.ProductIdalt="" style="width:90px;height:115px;" />
                </td>
                <td width="20%" valign="top">
                    <img src ="@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ShoppingBag"].ToString()@item.Image3" id ="Img3_"@item.ProductId alt="" style="width:90px;height:115px;" />
                </td>
                <td width="20%" valign="top">
                    <img src ="@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ShoppingBag"].ToString()@item.Image4" id ="Img4_"@item.ProductId alt="" style="width:90px;height:115px;" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductStatusCd)
                </td>
                @* <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
                </td>*@
            </tr>
        }

    </table>

<table id="listProduct">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.)*@
            Product ID
        </th>
        <th>Category / Sub Category 
        </th>
        <th>Image 1 
        </th>
        <th>Image 2 
        </th>
        <th>Image 3

        </th>
        <th>Image 4
        </th>
        <th>Product Status
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @*@Html.ActionLink(@item.ProductId, "FreezeProdView", "SellerLogin")*@
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category) / @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Subcategory)
            </td>
            <td width="20%" valign="top">
                <img src ="@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ShoppingBag"].ToString()@item.Image1" id = "Img1_"@item.ProductId alt="" style="width:90px;height:115px;" />
            </td>
            <td width="20%" valign="top">
                <img src ="@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ShoppingBag"].ToString()@item.Image2" id ="Img2_"@item.ProductIdalt="" style="width:90px;height:115px;" />
            </td>
            <td width="20%" valign="top">
                <img src ="@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ShoppingBag"].ToString()@item.Image3" id ="Img3_"@item.ProductId alt="" style="width:90px;height:115px;" />
            </td>
            <td width="20%" valign="top">
                <img src ="@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ShoppingBag"].ToString()@item.Image4" id ="Img4_"@item.ProductId alt="" style="width:90px;height:115px;" />
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductStatusCd)
            </td>
            @* <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
            </td>*@
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

If I get file,image Id, product id to my controller's action method  I can write the code to upload the file or edit the file.

My Controller is designed like this :

```
public string uploadProductImage(HttpPostedFileBase file, int productId,int imageId)
{

}
```

Comment: Please confirm to me: You want to know if the user clicked a button? Therefor you can use the Event OnButtonClick

Comment: @RageCompex I have 2 hyper links below every Image one is to upload and another is to delete. Now I want to get Clicked row's product Id ,ImageId and File in my controller how can i do that